# Toolbar для сортировки списка

Tags: android, ui, android-toolbar, toolbar

Как можно реализовать такой `Toolbar`, в который выводится (и изменяется) критерий для сортировки `RecyclerView`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы назначили Toolbar как ActionBar? вообще это обычный спиннер, в ActionBar (и Toolbar его заменяющий) он добавляется [примерно так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22901703/7566397). Если это просто Toolbar то все еще проще, просто добавляете в тулбар спиннер и все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш `Toolbar Spinner`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 .....

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_in_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

И в коде:

```
Spinner spinnerInToolbar = findViewById(R.id.spinner_in_toolbar);

spinnerInToolbar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // Действие когда выбран пункт из списка
    // Например, если выбран пункт 0, сортировка Linear
    // а если выбран пункт 1, сортировка Grid
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // Когда ничего не выбрано
}

});
```

P.S. Если же вы используете `ActionBar`, то решение в ссылке, которую предоставил `pavlofff`.